# cpanel sending email using gmail smtp in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, cpanel

I'm using wordpress 3.8, Mail SMTP plugin to send emails, and cpanel. In my local it works fine as my host is gmail. And once I uploaded it live I get authentication failed and I'm sure I typed my gmail username and password correctly. Is there any configuration that must be done? In cpanel perhaps? Or the plugin itself? Please help out. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please check you server is configurations done as per Googles Settings if your want to send mail through Google servers?

[Add MX entries for Google Apps In server](https://support.google.com/a/answer/140034?hl=en)

[Google SMTP email settings in Plugin](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13287?hl=en)

Otherwise you need to check the possibilities of your server to send email.

[Domain & Server capability Checking](http://www.intodns.com/) , [SMTP settings](http://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx)